# How to check an object is an ordered collection?

Tags: python

Which object of Python [ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) is guaranteed to be ordered and how to check?

[`Iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterator) with `next` method and [`Reversible`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Reversible) indicate order. Does `isinstance(object, (Iterator, Reversible))` cover all the cases if an object is ordered?

Comment: I'm pretty sure isinstance doesn't work with ABC types; you have to use `isinstance(object, iter)`, for example, unless something's changed in a recent version.

Comment: @BillHorvath there are three ways they work - inheritance, explicit registration ("virtual subclass") and, in some cases, introspection. It's listed at the top of the docs linked in the question.

Comment: Oops. My bad - I was thinking about the `typing` classes, not ABC. *facepalm*

Comment: Ordered collections *guarantee* a particular order. Iterators don't. You'll get elements in *an* order, simply because the iterator protocol produces elements one by one, but no order guarantees apply to iterators in general.

Comment: `Iterator` and `Reversible` are both subclasses of `Iterable`, which is probably what you are looking for if you aren't actually talking about *sorting* (which is a property of the type of element *in* the iterable, not the iterable itself).